# How to convert ObjectSet from Entities to IEnumerable of Models?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, casting, entity-framework-4.1, repository-pattern

I am building a test application using MVC3, Razor, and Entity Framework 4.1 with a schema-first approach (as apposed to a code-first approach), in a repository pattern. I would like to avoid accessing data objects in my view, and access a model instead, but I am having a problem. As far as I can tell, the data objects are being returned from the data layer as ObjectSet, but my View needs IEnumerable, and I don't know how to cast one to the other.

Here is some code, to help clarify.

---

**Model ...**

```
namespace TestSolution.Models
{
    public class ProjectModel
    {
        [HiddenInput]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(255, ErrorMessage = "The name cannot be more than 255 characters long.")]
        [Display(Name = "Name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Description")]
        public string Description { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Repository ...**

```
public IQueryable<ProjectModel> GetProjects()
{
    return Db.Project;
}
```

**Entities ...**

```
public ObjectSet<Project> Project
{
    get
    {
        if ((_Project == null))
        {
            _Project = base.CreateObjectSet<Project>("Project");
        }
        return _Project;
    }
}
```

**Controller ...**

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    IEnumerable<TestSolution.Models.ProjectModel> model = _projectRepository.GetProjects();
    return View(model);
}
```

**View ...**

```
@model IEnumerable<TestSolution.Models.ProjectModel>
```

**Error I am getting when building ...**

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Data.Objects.ObjectSet<TestSolution.Project>' to 'System.Linq.IQueryable<TestSolution.Models.ProjectModel>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)
```

---

Does this question make sense? I am just not sure where go from here ... any advise you guys can give me would be awesome. :)

**EDIT:** I was able to solve this with Kyle's suggestion by changing my Repository code to ...

```
public IQueryable<ProjectModel> GetProjects()
{
  return Db.Project.Select(i => new ProjectModel() { Id = i.Id, Name = i.Name, Description = i.Description });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem isn't converting from `ObjectSet<T>` to `IEnumerable<T>` ([`ObjectSet<T>` implements `IEnumerable<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd412719.aspx)).

The problem is converting from `TestSolution.Project` to `TestSolution.Models.ProjectModel`.  You will need to write some conversion code, maybe something similar to the below:

```
model.Select(i => new ProjectModel() { /* Set properties here. */ });
```

Comment: Thanks, guys. I'll take a look at some sort of conversion, as well as AutoMapper. I've never used AutoMapper before, but I'll take a look at it. But, I wonder, is Automapper the only way to do this? I am a little surprised I'd have conversion logic, in order to take advantage of MVC3 and EF 4.1 out-of-the-box. I thought I was just doing something wrong, not that I was missing a plug-in.

Comment: On second thought, I think I might just need to learn to write my data access logic better. I was able to get what I needed with Kyle's first suggestion, and it was really easy. Thanks! I will edit my original post with what I ended up using. I will also continue looking into AutoMapper.